# Seeking for construction s.t. every intersection contains at least 3 lines

Tags: euclidean-geometry

In Euclidean geometry, is there some set of lines in s.t. there are at least 2 intersections, but every intersection contains at least 3 lines, and no lines in the set are parallel?

I tried for a long time to construct this by hand but couldn't find a way, so I'm looking for a construction or a proof that one doesn't exist.

Thanks!

Comment: Interesting problem.  I am curious, what led you to it? Although tagged (euclidean-geometry), it might help clarify the problem if you state explicitly that you are talking about lines in the Euclidean plane (if that is the case).

Comment: Thanks, I've updated my post, what led me to it wasn't anything interesting, it was just something I thought of when I tried to find the maximum intersection of n lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible.  See the [Sylvester-Gallai theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%2DGallai_theorem) and in particular [Melchior's proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%2DGallai_theorem#Melchior.27s_proof).